# Pivoting a Dataframe after spliting header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to split the header and create a column with it's dates, so then I can perform some aggregations.

**How it looks right now**

```
     Gerencia             2021-01-01 00:00:00   2021-02-01 00:00:00          2021-03-01 00:00:00
0   Ingeniería de Producción    17.451383               7.633112                4.46176
1   Ingeniería de Producción    0.000000                0.000000                0
2   Ingeniería de Producción    17.437412               14.656419               2.87114
```

**How it should look**

[image]

**Question: How can be transformed in this way?**

I'm not sure if it should be managed with a lambda function or there is a simpler way with both pivot and pivot_table methods.

Comment: If you could post your data as a table and not an image, it would be way easier to help you.

Comment: use pd.melt give you the result you seek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `.melt` following by `.groupby`:

```py
df_out = (
    df.melt("Gerencia", var_name="Period", value_name="Sum")
    .groupby("Period", as_index=False)
    .agg({"Gerencia": "first", "Sum": "sum"})
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
                Period                  Gerencia        Sum
0  2021-01-01 00:00:00  Ingeniería de Producción  34.888795
1  2021-02-01 00:00:00  Ingeniería de Producción  22.289531
2  2021-03-01 00:00:00  Ingeniería de Producción   7.332900
```